# Triggering a software event from an interrupt (XMEGA, GCC)

Tags: events, gcc, interrupt, avr

I want to run a periodic "housekeeping" event, triggered regularly by a timer interrupt.  The interrupt fires frequently (kHz+), while the function may take a long time to finish, so I can't simply have it executed in line.

In the past, I've done this on an ATMEGA, where an ISR can simply permit other interrupts to fire (including itself again) with sei().  By wrapping the event in a "still executing" flag, it won't pile up on the stack and cause a... you know:

```
if (!inFunction) { inFunction = true; doFunction(); inFunction = false; }
```

I don't think this can be done -- at least as easily -- on the XMEGA, due to the PMIC interrupt controller.  It appears the interrupt flags can only be reset by executing RETI.

So, I was thinking, it would be convenient if I could convince GCC to produce a tail call out of an interrupt.  That would immediately execute the event, while clearing interrupts.

This would be easy enough to do in assembler, just push the address and IRET.  (Well, some stack-mangling because ISR, but, yeah.)  But I'm guessing it'll be a hack in GCC, possibly a custom ASM wrapper around a "naked" function?

Alternately, I would love to simply set a low priority software interrupt, but I don't see an intentional way to do this.

I could use software to trigger an interrupt from an otherwise unused peripheral.  That's fine as a special case, but then, if I ever need to use that device, I have to find another.  It's bad for code reuse, too.

Really, this is an X-Y problem and I know it.  I think I want to do X, but really I need method Y that I just don't know about.

One better method is to set a flag, then let main() deal with it when it gets around to it.  Unfortunately, I have blocking functions in main() (handling user input via serial), so that would take work, and be a mess.

The only "proper" method I know of offhand, is to do a full task switch -- but damned if I'm going to effectively implement an RTOS, or pull one in, just for this.  There's got to be a better way.

Have I actually covered all the possibilities, and painted myself into a corner?  Do I have to compromise and choose one of these?  Am I missing anything better?

Comment: The best way in you case would be indeed to set a flag in the ISR and let the main() handle the workload. Do not start with nested interrupts unless you have a very specific reason to do so. In general, try to keep the main-loop non-blocking and ISRs short. Waiting for user input can be easily handled asynchronously. "Blocking main" and "nested interrupts" / "very long interrupts" are things you (hopefully) won't find in code from experienced programmers. Novices tend to use that code style because its easy, but it is error prone and only allows limited complexity.

Answer (score 0):

There are more possibilities to solve this.

**1.** Enable your timer interrupt as *low priority*. In this way the medium and high priority interrupts will be able to interrupt this low priority interrupt, and run unaffected.

This is similar to using `sei();` in your interrupt handler in older processors (without PMIC).

**2.a** Set a *flag* (variable) in the interrupt. Poll the flag in the main loop. If the flag is set, clear it and do your stuff.

**2.b** Set up the timer but *don't enable* its interrupt. *Poll* the OVF interrupt flag of your timer in the main loop. If the flag is set, clear it and do your stuff.

These are timed less accurately according to what else the main loop does, so depends on your expectations for accuracy. Handling more tasks in the main loop without an OS: [Cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking), [State machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata-based_programming).